# Bash script/command to print out date 5 min before/after

Tags: bash

I need to somehow use the date command in bash or another utility to print out the date and time, 5 minutes before and 5 minutes after a given value. 
For example:

input:

```
Thu Dec 19 14:10
```

output:

```
Thu Dec 19 14:05 Thu Dec 19 14:10 Thu Dec 19 14:15
```

I see that the `date` command can be used to do this on the current date/time, can it be used with a passed value, i.e. not the current date/time?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can achieve this, for the current time, by typing.

```
$ date --date='5 minutes ago'; date; date --date='5 minutes'
Qui Dez 19 16:09:17 BRST 2013
Qui Dez 19 16:14:17 BRST 2013
Qui Dez 19 16:19:17 BRST 2013
```

To use a specific date (ex 1978/01/10).

```
$ date --date='1978-01-10 + 5 minutes'
Ter Jan 10 00:05:00 BRT 1978
```

Comment: And for doing it from poster's time spec, `isodate=$(date --rfc-3339=seconds -d "Thu Dec 19 14:10"); date -d "$isodate + 5 minutes"`

Comment: And for doing something for each date in the last three weeks: `for date in $(for daysago in $(seq 21 -1 0); do date --date "${daysago} days ago" +"%F"; done); do echo "use $date"; done` (wasn't asked for, I just thought I'd share)

Answer (score 22):

With GNU `date`, you can do a simple form of date/time arithmetic with the argument to the `--date` option:

```
$ date --date 'now + 5 minutes'
```

With BSD `date` (at least, the version that ships with Mac OS X), the `-v` option allows you to do something similar:

```
$ date -v +5M
$ date -v -5M
```

Comment: We need `coreutiles` when running alpine linux!

Comment: That's nothing to do with this question.

Comment: have you tried to implement this before? or you are just bitching around?

Comment: The question is about how to use `date`. How you install it is not my concern.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bash under linux, you can use the `-d` parameter to perform date manipulation on an *existing* date:

1. Get the EPOCH time for the date in question:

   ```
   EPOCH=$(date -d 'Thu Dec 19 14:10' '+%s')
   ```

   This gives you the time, *in seconds*, since the EPOCH (typically 01/01/1970)
2. Now you can use simple math to subtract or add 5 minutes (in seconds) to the EPOCH time

   ```
   NEW_EPOCH=$(($EPOCH - 300))
   ```

   *obviously, there are 300 seconds in 5 minutes*
3. Now convert this NEW_EPOCH back into a human readable date

   ```
   NEW_DATE=$(date -d "1970-01-01 ${NEW_EPOCH} sec")
   ```

*NOTE that this only works on unix systems which support the date -d option (i.e. Linux)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this for the current time +/-5 minutes and you use Bash 4.2 or newer, you can do it without external tools:

```
$ printf -v now '%(%s)T'
$ echo "$now"
1516161094
$ f='%a %b %d %R'
$ printf "%($f)T %($f)T %($f)T\n" "$((now-300))" "$now" "$((now+300))"
Tue Jan 16 22:46 Tue Jan 16 22:51 Tue Jan 16 22:56
```

The `%(datefmt)T` formatting string of [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) allows to print date-time strings. If the argument is skipped (like here) or is `-1`, the current time is used.

`%s` formats the time in seconds since the epoch, and `-v now` stores the output in `now` instead of printing it.

`f` is just a convenience variable so I don't have to repeat the formatting string for the output three times.

Since the argument for this usage of `printf` has to be in seconds since the epoch, you're stuck with external tools to convert an input string like `Thu Dec 19 14:10` into that format and you'd replace

```
printf -v now '%(%s)T'
```

with, for example, any of

```
now=$(date '+%s' -d 'Thu Dec 19 14:10')                   # GNU date
now=$(date -j -f '%a %b %d %T' 'Thu Dec 19 14:10' '+%s')  # macOS date
```

Comment: You must install `coreutils` in `alpine linux`