# Add seconds to current time in Bash

Tags: bash, date, time

I want to add 10 seconds 10 times. But I don't know well how to add times to the value.

This is my code.

**./time.sh**

```
time=$(date)
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 10 ] 
do
    echo "$time"
    time=$('$time + 10 seconds') //error occurred.
    ((counter++))
done

echo All done
```

Comment: Ah, actually, not an exact duplicate. Let me find a better one.

Comment: This one is close: [Bash script/command to print out date 5 min before/after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688664/bash-script-command-to-print-out-date-5-min-before-after)

Comment: @BenjaminW. - alas, that's a Linux-specific solution. This question is about adding seconds in **bash**, rather than using external tools like `date`.

Comment: I'm about to add a Bash specific solution.

Comment: @ghoti Also, the OP uses `date`, so I assume that's not off limits.

Comment: @BenjaminW. ... I wouldn't assume that anything the OP has posted is accurate. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using GNU Date

Assuming GNU `date`, replace:

```
time=$('$time + 10 seconds')
```

with:

```
time=$(date -d "$time + 10 seconds")
```

Putting it all together, try:

```
$ cat a.sh
t=$(date)
counter=1
while [ "$counter" -le 10 ]
do
    echo "$t"
    t=$(date -d "$t + 10 seconds")
    ((counter++))
done

echo All done
```

(I renamed `time` to `t` because `time` is also a bash built-in command and it is best to avoid potential confusion.)

When run, the output looks like:

```
$ bash a.sh
Tue Jan 16 19:19:44 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:19:54 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:20:04 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:20:14 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:20:24 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:20:34 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:20:44 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:20:54 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:21:04 PST 2018
Tue Jan 16 19:21:14 PST 2018
All done
```

#### Using Bash (>4.2)

Recent versions of bash support date calculations without external utilities.  Try:

```
$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash
printf -v t '%(%s)T' -1
counter=1
while [ "$counter" -le 10 ]
do
    ((t=t+10))
    printf '%(%c)T\n' "$t"
    ((counter++))
done

echo All done
```

Here, `t` is time since epoch in seconds.

When run, the output looks like:

```
$ bash b.sh
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:31:44 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:31:54 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:32:04 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:32:14 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:32:24 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:32:34 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:32:44 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:32:54 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:33:04 PM PST
Tue 16 Jan 2018 07:33:14 PM PST
All done
```

Comment: A `date` based solution is necessarily platform specific, and is not portable within the realm of operating systems on which bash can run. The `-d` option, in particular, is part of the version of the command from GNU coreutils; the BSD `date` command is very different. Can you provide a solution that is specific to `bash` rather than requiring external tools whose behaviour can't be predicted?

Comment: I got the error like    

    2018. 01. 17. (수) 12:25:42 KST
    date: invalid date ‘2018. 01. 17. (수) 12:25:42 KST + 10 seconds’

    What's the different with you?

Comment: @user7140475 - comments are a *terrible* place for formatted text. Please add your results to your question.

Comment: Sorry it's first time i ask question in stackoverflow. here is my '$bash --version' result. **GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)**

Comment: @user7140475 There must be something peculiar about the date format of your locale.  As an alternative and since you are using a recent version of bash, try the bash-only version that I just added.

Comment: @ghoti Good idea.  The OP is using a recent bash.  The answer is updated with a bash-only method.

Comment: @John1024 - awesome. You get my vote. :)

Comment: Cool!! it's work. Thank you so much. :)